# Network Fluctuating

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, windows-server-2008-r2, pppoe

Am working an a small business and i have over 20 client computers on my LAN and i am having a windows Server 2008 R2 on the LAN also which is my dns server. My ISP installed a bridge (outdoor) that connects to their Base Station and that bridge is connected to an indoor POE (Power Over Ethernet) device. My problem is my network is Fluctuating, when i restart the device (PPPOE) after some minutes its back on and i can browse the internet  but just for few hours and sometimes only minutes its goes down again and i'll have to restart the (PPPOE) again.

But when i connect only my laptop to the ethernet cable connecting the LAN  i can browse and have access to the internet but if i connect the ethernet cable back to the (PPPOE) device my clients cant have access to the internet.

Any advice on what to check on or do, i'll really appreciate it.

Comment: That is slightly odd I have to admit. Any chance you can put something inbetween the POE and the PPPOE device maybe a small switch just to 'break' the direct connection between them?

Comment: @user338877 How do you see this fluctuations? by browsing?! That's not a very accurate test.
You should test it with pings (with '-t' switch) from one of the stations in your network to: 1. another station in your network 2. to the switch (if it's possible) 3. to the first 'hop' outside your network.
Give it some time and see what results you get.